# How can I find a way to prove that the following matrix is not positive-semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra

I currently have a matrix that looks like:

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & -5 \\
3 & -5 & 10 \end{array} \right) $

I am trying to prove that this matrix is not positive semi-definite, the definition of which is:

If a matrix is called positive-semidefinite if:

$x^{*} M x \geq 0$
for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have been trying to find that $x$ vector, but to no avail. Is there a program I can run to find the counter example? Thank you!

Comment: You could note that the bottom right $2\times 2$ submatrix isn't positive semidefinite since its determinant $2\cdot 10 - (-5)^2 = -5$ is negative.

Comment: The principal minor $M_{(2,3;2,3)}$ is negative.

Comment: In general, consider eigenvectors corresponding to negative eigenvalues (you don't even need to know the actual entries of the eigenvector; what's really important is that the eigenvalue is negative).

Comment: Or you could just look for a vector with $v^t M v < 0$; I think that $v = [0, 2, 1]^t$ works. (And I found it by looking for a way to use the negative entries in $M$ effectively, i.e., I started with $[0,1,0]$ and $[0,0,1]$ and played around a little.)

Comment: See [Sylvester's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion)

Comment: The determinant is negative and we're done with that. @Daniel, why that non-principal minor being non-positive would give the matrix is non positive definite?

Comment: @Timbuc Because it's the matrix of the restriction to a certain two-dimensional subspace, and if the restriction to a subspace isn't positive semidefinite, then the form cannot be.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer, I have to think a little more on this as I find it surprising they give *explicitly* the **principal** minors condition but not other square sub-matrices of the original one...but I'm still trying to open my way into these things.

Comment: @Timbuc It's less work to check only the principal minors than all the (symmetric with respect to the row- and column-indices) minors. But for any such minor, there is a change of basis that makes it a principal minor (here use the basis $(e_2,e_3,e_1)$), and a change of basis doesn't change the (semi)definiteness of the form.

Comment: That I understood, @DanielFischer. Thank you very much.